# How do I check on whether my synchronized methods are blocking (Android + Java)

Tags: java, android

I have a feeling that my synchorization may be a little coarse (juddering UI) and was wondering how do I find out when/if my synchronized java methods are blocking on each other.  My current project is on Android but I am interested in the more general Java case as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

How does your UI behave if you remove all uses of `synchronized` from your UI thread? If it's suddenly smooth and responsive, then you know it is indeed blocking for too long while waiting for other threads to release locks.

If however it makes no difference and it's still juddery, you know the problem is your background threads are too busy, i.e. are starving your UI thread of CPU time.

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned above I would really like to know if my app is blcoking.  Without sychronizing my database can get corrupted in seconds (pretty sure theres a problem with Android implementation of SQLite) so I might wait a while before trying this.  It also reminds me that having come from c++ to java which I love, I do miss #define which would be very useful for this.

Comment: I really hope you're not doing any Database stuff in a method that's synchronized with your UI thread! Remember how slowww flash-based I/O is. How about you fill your question in with a little more detail about whats actually going on?

Comment: Well I didnt really want this to be about my specific problem, but how in general you get access to when synchorized methods are blocking.  In my case I have a cache and a database wrapped up in an class, the UI only ever reads the cache and other threads read from the database and put stuff into the cache, so I wanted to know if these puts were colliding with the UI reads since I am pretty sure I could make the synchronization more fine but would like to know before hand whether I am fixing a problem that doesnt exist.

Comment: Well you could always read the system clock just before you enter a 'synchronized' block on the UI thread, and then read it again *inside* the synchronized block, and thereby find out how much time it spent waiting to access the locked object...

Answer (score 2):

By profiling your application using [traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html) you can see how much time is spent in each function (Including and excluding the function itself).

I think this should help.

Comment: Thanks, I have already done this and the app is behaving as expected, the juddering is occasional so I would really like to know when I get blocks rather than overall performance.